# How to delete particular object from array using mongoose express and angular

Tags: angular, express, mongoose

I m using mongoose express nodjs and angular to develop my project.
I store user request into particular user account. I dont no how to delete a particular object from array.

here is my data stored in array in database

```html
_v
:1
requests
:
Array

    0
    :
    Object
        _id
        :ObjectId(5ece0bb3fdba2015bca0a052)
        bloodgroup
        :"A+"
        city
        :"g"
    1
    :
    Object
        _id
        :ObjectId(5ece0b6bfdba2015bca0a051)
        bloodgroup
        :"A+"
        city
        :"jj"
    2
    :
    Object
        _id
        :ObjectId(5ece0b6bfdba2015bca0a051)
        bloodgroup
        :"A+"
        city
        :"j
```

here is how i delete

```html
router.post('/delete', verifyToken, (req, res) => {
    let userData = req.body;
    const userId = req.userId;
    User.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: userId},{$pull: {requests: {_id: userData._id}}}, {multi:true} ,(error,user) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error)
       } else 
           if (!user) {
               res.status(401).send('user Does not exists')
           } else { 
             user.save()
              res.status(200).send(user)
           }
    })
})
```

here is my comonent.ts

```html
 onReject(event: Event) {
    const target = event.target as HTMLInputElement ;
    const val =  target.value ;
    const user_id = val;
    console.log(user_id);
   this.auth.deleteRequests(user_id)
    .subscribe(
       res=>{
         
       console.log(res)       },
      err => console.log(err)
     )
  }
```

please help me to solve this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this `{$pull: {requests: {_id: userData._id}}}` part of your code to this:

`{$pull: {requests: userData._id}}` and it'll work.